# No option for installing any aap in Software Center

Tags: software-installation, software-center

There is no any option for installing the flash player but has a More info button. Even if I click the 'More info' button it says check your Internet connection.

But there is no issue with my Internet connection as I have a working broadband connection and it's connected.

Comment: Which browser are you using? Firefox? Chrome? Chromium?

Comment: Does `sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer` work from a terminal window?

Comment: What *version* of Ubuntu do you have?

Comment: I am using Firefox 24.0, pre installed with Ubuntu 13.04. I'm not able to install any software neither by software center nor by terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You probably not adding the `multiverse` repository.

```
$ apt-cache policy flashplugin-installer
flashplugin-installer:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 11.2.202.460ubuntu0.12.04.1
  Version table:
     11.2.202.460ubuntu0.12.04.1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
     11.2.202.440ubuntu0.12.04.1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     11.2.202.233ubuntu2 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/multiverse amd64 Packages
```

This shows that `flashplugin-installer` in multiverse repository so to solve your problem you have to enable it. To enable it run the command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main  multiverse"
```

Now you have to update your source list

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Now you can install it eaither from software center or by command line using the command:

```
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

Comment: nothing happened. Problem are still there.